# Erro no horário de verão (summer time) no bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, localização, datepicker

O plugin parou de funcionar com o início do horário de verão no Brasil. Quando desabilito a opção na minha máquina (*Ajustar automaticamente para o horário de verão*) o plugin volta a funcionar.

Código:

```
$('.campodata').datetimepicker({
    useSeconds: false,
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM'
});
```

Erro no console:

[image: Erro no Console do chrome]

Comment: Bem vindo a StackOverflow em português, vulgo SOpt. Editei sua pergunta para remover a parte em inglês(não escrevemos em inglês para explicar o problema), também retirei sua saudação, pois como as pessoas leem em horários diferentes ela perde o sentido, nosso foco está sempre nas perguntas e respostas, pode parecer grosseiro de minha parte, mas é uma convenção que temos aqui :)

Comment: Da uma olhada aqui: https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker
Tem um link pra uma demo online, tenta reproduzir o problema que você está tendo na sua aplicação, se acontecer vc pode abrir uma issue ou tentar resolver o problema. Caso não aconteça, vc pode tentar da uma olhada senao tem nada de errado no seu código.

Comment: Arthur, qual é a versão do datepicker que estás a usar?

Comment: Ele dá algum erro? No meu simplesmente não funciona, sem erro no console....

Answer (score 1):

Tive esse problema recentemente. Para corrigí-lo editei um trecho o método fill do bootstrap-datepicker que antes era assim:

```
var prevMonth = new Date(year, month - 1, 28, 0, 0, 0, 0),
   day = DPGlobal.getDaysInMonth(prevMonth.getFullYear(), prevMonth.getMonth());
```

E depois ficou assim:

```
var prevMonth = new Date(year, month - 1, 28, 12, 0, 0, 0),
   day = DPGlobal.getDaysInMonth(prevMonth.getFullYear(), prevMonth.getMonth());
```

E o método parseDate, onde era:

```
date.setHours(0);
```

Ficou:

```
date.setHours(12);
```

Comment: Sua nota de rodapé cabe bem no seu "Sobre mim", que diga-se de passagem está vazio. O site costuma evitar qualquer tipo de interferência nas publicações, seja na pergunta ou nas respostas. Aqui costumamos evitar saudações, agradecimentos e propagandas. Se o seu link fosse vital para o entendimento da resposta faria sentido em mantê-lo, mas do jeito que está é meramente promocional e foge do escopo do site. Qualquer dúvida pode consultar o [meta].